# Play AVKit fullscreen videos in landscape in fully portrait app, iOS 12 edition

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, avkit

When one need to make full-screen `AVPlayer` support landscape orientation in a portrait only app the most prevalent recommendation is to add `AVFullScreenViewController` somehow as an exception and make it support landscape orientation. E.g., add a comparison for this class name to `supportedInterfaceOrientations(for:)` method in your `AppDelegate`.

However, it never worked for me (although I has checked it only in iOS 11) and I had to add such an exception for my `UIViewController` subclass which contains video as a subview. (And in my case, to make a workaround to make this view controller support only portrait mode when video is not in full-screen and support both portrait and landspace orientations when video is in full-screen.)

Surprisingly enough, it doesn't work in iOS 12. A small research detected that Apple changed full-screen presentation mechanism in AVKit internally. (A noticeable sign to avoid using internal APIs.)

Previous version of view hierarchy is based on `UIWindow` instance that holds `UITransitionView` and, in parallel, you view hierarchy. `UITransitionView` holds that `AVFullScreenViewController` instance.
([iOS11 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni0Gf.png))

iOS 12 version of view hierarchy looks very different: TWO windows this time. First one is familiar `UIWindow` which holds your view hierarchy. Second one is new for me – `AVWindow` instance which holds `UITransitionView` with `AVFullScreenViewController` inside it and a `UIViewController` uncertain subclass as a sibling.
([iOS12 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6d1F.png))

When I'm trying to rotate screen `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method is called for both `AVFullScreenViewController` and that unknown `UIViewController` subclass. (More precisely, I can't be sure that `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is called for that `UIViewController` subclass exactly, but most likely it is.)

So, has anyone else faced this problem? Is there a solution or a workaraound?

Thanks for your partaking in advance!

P.S. I'm sorry for painting over my internal class names, this screenshots are taken from my company project.

P.P.S. For now I ended up in supporting all orientations for window in my `AppDelegate` and overriding `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in every view controller subclass to support portrait only.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentations, this workaround somehow works for me @ appdelegate.m

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    // play-video-then-back fix
    if (@available(iOS 12, *)) {
        // not key-window, allow anti-rotate, while keywindow rotate
        if (window.isKeyWindow != YES)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }

...
}
```

edit: also .plist-enabled "View controller-based status bar appearance" = YES, but maybe not relevant